# Purpose of "code" kwarg in ValidationError constructor

Tags: python, django

What is the purpose of the `code` keyword argument that can be passed to a `ValidationError` constructor? It seems that it is customary to use the name of a key in a form's `error_messages` dictionary if defined. Nevertheless, from what I can see `code` is not used for any particular purpose by Django itself.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Source Code, it says that it is because Python2 had a `message` attribute, so they can't duck type on it, so they used `code` instead for compatibility.  Here's the Source Code link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/core/exceptions/#ValidationError